# How to confine a docker container to a Docker Network

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

Below is my docker compose file :

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  docker-mysql:
    image: mysql
    container_name: docker-mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=user_management
    networks:
      - technet
networks:
  technet:
    name: technet
```

Now I want to start the MySQL container in **technet** network with the name **docker-mysql**. Next, I will change the network to **technet2** in the docker-compose.yml manually and username and password but start with same container and image name.

Currently, the behavior is the old container in the **technet** is stopped and rebuilt inside the **technet2** network. But I want to have 2 containers of MySQL with the same container name **docker-mysql** but in a different network i.e. **technet** and **technet2**.

Comment: I think you can not start the same container with two diff networks yes you can create 2 diff container with diff network. However you can communicate between these containers using dredge or host-only network

Comment: @AshishJagtap Yes, I want two different containers in two different network. But the container names should be the same. Could you please walk me through the process of achieving this?

Comment: You can not have two containers with the same name on one machine (See [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#container_name) ).